# Project Management tool that connects with versioning system

Tags: project-management, version-control

I am looking for a project management solution that connects with Versioning systems and Continuous Integration.

Overall requirements are as follows:

1. Self site hosted (not cloud based)
2. Web based system
3. Helps visualising product roadmaps - i.e. milestones, phases etc.
4. support standard project management tools like Gantt etc.
5. Being open source will be great preference but not a MUST.

Now here is something unique that I need:

I want to integrate this with GIT LAB - where following can be achieved in the project -

- new issues posted either from project-management-system to GitLab or other wise gets populated on either side.
- git lib issues, and their status can be automatically fetched to update the status of the project progress

Basically, lot of work related to specs or requirement translates both in terms of "issues" for the software versioning systems - and at the same time, they translate as "work-items" for project management. So I don't quite want to replicate this back-n-forth manually.

Any suggestion?

So far I have considered OpenProject, ]Project Open[, .mycollab.com - but I don't have a way to connect these webApps to GitLab.